# Making responsive iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I tried to create a responsive iframe, it renders good on pc but is not responsive if we consider mobile devices.
Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtskemmh/)

Here is my **HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="noScrolling">
<iframe class="inner"     src="https://www.initialstate.com/embed/#/tiles/kkCIxiV4PJmg6y88ldn5HvhNiALMBdHp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
        .outer{
    position: relative;
    background: url(background-with-backdrop.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
        //width:420px;
        height:800px;
    }
     .inner{
     position: relative;
        left: 300px;
        top: 75px;
        width:1050px;
        height:582px;

    }

    .noScrolling{
        width: 1050px; /*or any other size*/
        height: 800px; /*or any other size*/       
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have control over the content in the iframe ?

Comment: no, ifarme's content is loading from other site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you trying to do something like this ?
Check out this [link](http://resume.justthingsido.com/#projects)
the iframe in that page resizes according to the width of the viewport

check this out.. i sort of gave you my own implementation of your problem.

**EDIT**

I am going to try and explain what i did.

- The key here is to use percentages rather than pixel. Pixels are are absolute and percentages are relative and seem to work better when things are changing with the viewport. 
  and it seems this is a one page site, and the background seems to be full sized to the viewport, then it is a good idea to use `vw and vh` units for the width and height since they rescale the content of your size according to the size of the window.

Now if we look at the CSS, i have set the `body` as the container and given it a `width and height of 100vw, and 100vh` respectively.

Then everything else inside this container can start using a percentage of the dimensions of body.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://wrb.farm/demo/background-with-backdrop.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.noScrolling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 54%;
  height: 73%;
  top: 9%;
  left: 23%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="noScrolling">
        <iframe scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" class="inner" src="https://www.initialstate.com/embed/#/tiles/kkCIxiV4PJmg6y88ldn5HvhNiALMBdHp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The only iframe I see on that site is the one to http://zamorany.com/ but it's gone when you view the parent page at a certian breakpoint. Is there another iframe?

Comment: That's slick, but I'm not the OP, is that the relevant code?

Comment: @zer00ne i thought you were OP. haha Sorry.. and Once again i forgot to comment the changes ahha

Comment: Naw, I'm always interested in iframes, and this'll be bookmarked for further study ;)

Comment: @zer00ne yeah i am interested in the aswell. I have used them in a couple of projects and for some reason they are always kind of hard to use since some websites are really hard code and somehow its sometimes impossible to remove the scroll bars, and you got to hope those websites are responsive, as in this example, if the website wasn't responsive it would have never worked.

Comment: @Guille, that solved my problem. I tried to hide scrollbars using overflow:hidden and or overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden. But the scrollbars just dont disappear, is there any other approach to do it in your code?

Comment: @KilvishShakal i have tried the same thing, and if you notice i have also tried to do so from the `iframe` tag. But it seems it is not working. It appears that it is something that is hard coded in that website so there is nothing you can do unless you have control over that website.

Answer (score 1):

As an update for  others coming in the future, you can do this in native javascript without any need for a framework/library with [Responsive Iframes](https://github.com/taylordaughtry/responsive-iframes).

Answer (score 0):

Making responsive iframe became more easy with a tool called "responsive iframer".

**How to work with that:**

1. It is so simple to do. Just go to this link:
   https://ilav.xyz/responsive-iframe
2. Give the link and some other details that you may need.
3. Go down and click the check for the copy button.
4. Then paste it where you want.

Check this: https://ilav.xyz/html-editor?responsiveiframe