# Responsive iframe, how to remove overflow border

Tags: html, css, iframe, overflow, responsive

I'm trying to embed a video using an iframe but I'm getting some annoying overflow padding that I can't seem to get rid of.

The code at the top is a way of forcing an iframe into a responsive style so that you can view it on mobile.

Basically the 'padding-bottom' code is controlling the aspect ratio of the frame.

I got the code from here:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/

I've checked here: [Making responsive iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376585/making-responsive-iframe) and this leaves me with horrible overflow too.

The result is below:

[Image displaying overflow issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1FeW.png)

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://06-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/4345/3/96727205/257828362.mp4?expires=1497358367&token=0ef4c2c1316f5f76d532a" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Changing the padding-bottom: to 56.35% just moves the black overflow line to the bottom of the video instead of the side.

Comment: The image doesn't work so it's hosted here:https://ibb.co/cH3Q8Q

Comment: It does - it's just new users can't inline images. Once you have 10 rep you will be able to.

Comment: i created a fiddle. everything is working fine... https://jsfiddle.net/8uL0jw3j/1/ or so it seems also edited your question with a snippet

Comment: I found out what it was myself: It's a user agent stylesheet addition: black background on the overflow. Temp fix is to remove the colour.

I tried your code snippet and it broke the container.

Answer (score 0):

height `100vh` will take 100% of viewport and `margin:0` and `padding:0` remove default properties.

Just add

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
} 

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%; /* Add this */
    height: 100vh; /* Add this */
    padding:0px; /* Add this */
    margin:0px; /* Add this */
}
```

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://06-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/4345/3/96727205/257828362.mp4?expires=1497358367&token=0ef4c2c1316f5f76d532a" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this instead. It works - gets around the user agent style sheet that Chrome uses and applies correct styling.

```
<style type="text/css">
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="video-container">
    <video style="width:100%;" src="https://06-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/4345/3/96727205/257828362.mp4?expires=1497358367&token=0ef4c2c1316f5f76d532a" controls autoplay type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://06-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/4345/3/96727205/257828362.mp4?expires=1497358367&token=0ef4c2c1316f5f76d532a" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```